# php sanitize an array with a given function

Tags: php

I have a simple sanitize function that nests a switch statement inside of a foreach statement which I read somewhere is a bad practice, but I haven't been able to come up with a better solution, my code is as follows, any help would be appreciated...

```
public static function DB_Sanitize($input, $santype = 'SQL', $cleanKeys = FALSE) {
    $type = strtoupper($santype);
    if (!is_array($input)) {
        $input = array($input);
    }
    foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
        switch ($type) {
            case 'SQL':
                if ($cleanKeys) {
                    $key = $this->_mysqli->escape_string($key);
                }
                $value = $this->_mysqli->escape_string($value);
                $clean[$key] = $value;
                break;
            case 'HTML':
                if ($cleanKeys) {
                    $key = htmlentities($key);
                }
                $value = htmlentities($value);
                $clean[$key] = $value;
                break;
            default:
                if ($cleanKeys) {
                    $key = $this->_mysqli->escape_string($key);
                }
                $value = $this->_mysqli->escape_string($value);
                $clean[$key] = $value;
                break;
    }
    return $clean;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be doing sql escaping like this anyways. Prepared statements and/or placeholders almost totally remove the need for this. And you shouldn't be storing "mangled" html in the db anyways. Clean the html when you retrieve and know what you're going to be using it for.

Comment: If you do a foreach within the switch, you'll have more code, but less execution time as the switch checks aren't executed for every tiem. Depends how many values you have in the $input tbh..

Comment: thank you marc b, but for the purpose of 'optional' prepared statements what do you think I should do?, I figured that because prepared statements are primarily used for reducing execution time, they probably shouldn't be used as a matter of course for statements that will only be executed once. thanks for that user1020317, so you're saying that a switch is kind of like an if statement where code is only executed if the condition is true, so the checking of conditions and the chosen condition take up time in the script

Comment: Why does a method named `DB_Sanitize` – emphasis on __DB__ – want to do escaping for the context HTML anyways?

Comment: the html sanitize is for data that's already been pulled from the database, in the case of data that may be code or have been inputed by the user, but more likely code in the database in my case, the end goal is a repository to help me manage my code, how can I post a sample of what I'm working on without answering my own post?, mainly some DB classes and some active record

Comment: marc b, I'll look into prepared statements, i've been delaying long enough

Comment: also, user1020317, I took the switch statement out (below) of the foreach loop because of what you said about the number of checks and it worked, cbroe, thanks for the question

Answer (score 0):

```
public function DB_Sanitize($input, $context = 'SQL', $cleanKeys = FALSE) {

    $type = gettype($input);
    $context = strtoupper($context);
    if (!is_array($input)) {
        $input = array($input);
    }
    switch($context) {
        case 'SQL':
            $filter = array('options' => array($this->_mysqli, 'escape_string'));
            break;
        case 'HTML':
            $filter = 'html_entities';
            break;
        default:
            $filter = array('options' => array($this->_mysqli, 'escape_string'));
            break;
    }
    foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
        if ($type == 'string') $strkey = $key;
        if ($cleanKeys && is_string($key)) {
            $key = filter_var($key, FILTER_CALLBACK, $filter);
        }
        $value = filter_var($value, FILTER_CALLBACK, $filter);
        $clean[$key] = $value;
    }
    if (isset($strkey)) return $clean[$strkey];
    return $clean;

}
```