# specify callback params for filter_var in php

Tags: php

I have this:

```
$value = filter_var($value, FILTER_CALLBACK, 'mysqli_real_escape_string');
```

and I'm getting the message:

```
Warning: filter_var() [function.filter-var]: First argument is expected to be a 
valid callback in C:\mypath\Database.class.php on line 285
```

but the manual clearly states that the first argument of filter_var is the input string, any ideas?

Comment: Since you need to pass a connection parameter to `mysqli_real_escape_string`, this won't work either way. You need at least an anonymous closure wrapper which passes the connection parameter.

Comment: Also, `mysqli_real_escape_string` works only when you connected to database, also `The character set must be set either at the server level, or with the API function mysqli_set_charset() for it to affect mysqli_real_escape_string(). See the concepts section on character sets for more information.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the syntax for `FILTER_CALLBACK` your callback should be in array. Since `mysqli_real_escape_string` takes two arguments, your code wouldn't work even if you followed right syntax. Try to make your own function.

```
$value = filter_var($value, FILTER_CALLBACK, array('options'=>'YOUR_CALLBACK_HERE'));
```

Comment: I'm going to try a closure and post back, maybe not today

Comment: Still haven't gotten to the closure but I will comment back as soon as possible.

Answer (score 4):

The docs are not very clear. The argument needs to be an array with the key options being your callable. In addition, `mysqli_real_escape_string` expects two arguments, the database link and the string:

```
$value = filter_var($value, FILTER_CALLBACK,
  array('options' => array('mysqli', 'real_esacpe_string')));
```

Comment: There's another problem.  `mysqli_real_escape_string` can't be used as a callback here.  From the docs: "The callback must accept one argument, the value to be filtered".  `mysqli_real_escape_string` wants 2 arguments, so it can't be used.  You're gonna need to make your own function as a "wrapper".

Comment: @RocketHazmat I'm not that familiar with PHP prior to 5.3. Is it possible to do it without using `global $link;`?

Comment: tried: $value = filter_var($value, FILTER_CALLBACK, array($this->_mysqli, 'escape_string')); but that doesn't seem to work either, it seems it should negate the link problem, also tried $value = filter_var($value, FILTER_CALLBACK, array(get_class($this->_mysqli), 'escape_string'));

Comment: @user1205600: Try `$value = filter_var($value, FILTER_CALLBACK, array('options' => array($this, 'real_escape_string'));`

Comment: @Paulpro: The way you have it in your answer should be correct.  I'd suggest, however, to *not* use procedural style and do:  `$value = filter_var($value, FILTER_CALLBACK, array('options' => array($mysqli, 'real_escape_string'));`  Where `$mysqli` is `$mysqli = new mysqli(...)`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yeah, that's definitely the way to go. I didn't realize you could make a static method callable using an array like that. Thanks!

Comment: you should answer with your comment, this so I can say it worked: $value = filter_var($value, FILTER_CALLBACK, array('options' => array($this->_mysqli, 'real_escape_string')));

Comment: @Paulpro: Yeah, the "callable" type is kinda weird.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

Comment: @user1205600: You need `array('options' => ` because that's how `filter_var` works, it's not really explained well.

Comment: my original post and final code ( thanks everybody ): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490917/php-sanitize-an-array-with-a-given-function/18495463#18495463